# Eclipse 3.8: Call Hierarchy misses callers from jars

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, callstack, eclipse-jdt

The *Call Hierarchy* view in Eclipse JDT 3.8 seems to show only the references / callers from the *own classes* in the current project / working set. 

***Callers from jars / libraries are not shown any more***.

In contrast, in eclipse <= **3.6** this **showed all callers, including** the ones from **libraries**.

***Example:***

1. `CTRL-SHIFT-T`; open `DocumentBuilderFactory`
2. In the method outline, right click at `setAttribute()`
3. Select `Call Hierarchy` from context menu
4. Ensure *Show Caller Hierarchy* is enabled in the Call hierarchy settings.

*Eclipse 3.8 shows no matches, while Eclipse 3.6 shows (at least) one match*
(tested with jdk 6)

(In the "Search in" setting, all options are checked)

**Question: 
*Is there a way to enable the previous behavior in eclipse 3.8 or is it a bug?***

(same issue can be seen in the "Show Callee Hierachy" mode - it does not show any internal callees any more from a jdk class, e.g. compare callees of `ArrayList.get()`)

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have any filters applied?

Comment: @DaveRlz Yes, no filters are applied. And BTW, it's a clean installation. Have you tried to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I get one caller in `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.encryption.XMLCipher.Serializer.deserialize(String, Node)` in `rt.jar` in Eclipse Juno (Java EE edition)

Comment: artbristol: Thank you for this comment. It seems that it might not  be necessarily a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In Call Hierarchy View, click on the drop down arrow, select 'Search in' and check the 'Application libraries' box.

Comment: as stated in the question, all of these checkboxes are checked.